# Prevent table from adding more than a row

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the way of implementing a configuration table, the table suppose to have only one row at all time.

Is there a way in `Sql Server 2008` to prevent table from adding more than a row?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a static, computed, column and make it unique.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD UniqueKey AS 1 PERSISTED CONSTRAINT UQ_MyTable_UniqueKey UNIQUE
```

If someone adds a row, it will cause a unique constraint violation

Comment: Thanks!! what does `PERSISTED` meant?

Comment: @SSS: it is required to make the computed column persistent (instead of calculated on demand) so the unique index can be created